# Manipulation of keys in dict-of-dicts in python

Tags: python, dictionary

In python, given a dict-of-dicts, say:

```
example = {0: {}, 1: {'foo': 0}, 2: {'foo': 1}, 3: {'foo':0, 'bar':1}, 4: {'bar':0}}
```

And a particular key (perhaps) stored in one or more of the inner dictionaries, I'd like to find the outer key and inner value associated with that key.

Obviously, simply iterating over the outer keys works:

```
value = 'foo'
for outer_key in example:
    if value in example[outer_key]:
        do_things()
```

Is that a good/Pythonic way to do this?  I've encountered several variants on this structure, which seems awkward when you need the inner keys without necessarily knowing them or where they are.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What's "the outer key and inner value" associated with (e.g.) `'foo'` in your example? Why not rework your data structure to look things up based on the inner key in the first place?

Comment: Other people's packages.  

Here, I'd like to find out that key 1 has foo value 0, key 2 has foo value 1, and key 3 has foo value 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be slightly more pythonic, you might want to iterate over the `items` of `example`:

```
for outer_key, inner_dict in example.items():
    if value in inner_dict:
        do_things()
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can find out the key associated with a value in a dictionary is by iterating over the dict. Im sorry but there's no other way that I am aware of.